# PowerShell try catch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I need you help Im using the next script:
[How to get all groups within all webs in SharePoint 2010 using Powershell](http://smallcitydesign.com/how-to-get-all-groups-within-all-webs-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/)

The script perfectly, but some user can not be found, so I'm trying to control the errors and send them to a file, I try:

```
catch [System.Exception]{
    "ERROR: " + $($_.Exception.Message)| out-file $logfile -append
}
```

But this does not work, the catch never write the file as if it never entered in the catch, but in screen I see the errors

Comment: Marco: can you please confirm what you mean by does not work?

Comment: the catch never write the file as if it never entered in the catch, but in screen I see the errors

Comment: Marco: Please post your complete code. Powershell error handling works in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all of that.  Try just:

```
catch {
    "Error: " + $_.Exception.Message | out-file $logfile -append
}
```

Comment: didn't work, see the attached image
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=22471741AAB453D0!10547&authkey=!AK_FpngQwMekwCY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

idk how to attach images in comments